# Coldfusion Component eating JVM memory

Tags: java, coldfusion, garbage-collection

Im trying some of the heap size management suggestions but it's a slow process...
I want to post some coe in hope of someone making a suggestion ...

I'm analyzing data against scenarios - and the analysis is somewhat complex, but not terrible.
However when I try to run a scenario against 1000 different data sets... I crash my server,

I've got a sample size of 100000 data sets - and need to run scenarios against this set - 
I find that I can loop 10-20 set, and then the system eats itself... The JVM memory climbs to max.

I have to clear component cache and run the GC from the server monitor to get the memory usage down, but when I run the loop again - it soon climbs out of control.

```
<cfscript>
x = 20;
obj = createObject( 'component', 'b' );

d = obj.insertData( FORM.DATA );
s = obj.insertScenario( FORM.SCENARIO );

Xscenarios = obj.getXscenarios( s, d, x );
// analyze x 
for( i=1; i <=arrayLen( Xscenarios ); i++ ) {
    a = obj.analyze( Xscenarios[i], s );
}
</cfscript>
```

Each analysis takes about 3 seconds....

Any suggestions?

How do I force GC after each loop? Do I want to? Should I?

Comment: Do you have some of the code for `analyze()` ?

Comment: James, I would but the analyze code is extensive.... and "may" be the culprit, but the memory leak is apparently fix in CF10 (I upgraded my dev system once I foo-bar'd it dinking with some settings.) Once I get the server monitor woking in 10 I'll look at it in detail.

Answer (score 0):

Java doesn't recommend to call forcefully GC. try to optimize your code and query that might be eating your memory or you can manage your jvm size by defining -Xms256m and -Xmx512m properties in your container configuration.

Comment: Please make configuration according to your system specs, I think you have defined jvm properties more then your available system ram.

Comment: a) If you killed your server, you can bring it back by using the backup copy of your `jvm.xml`. b) ColdFusion does come out the box with way too little memory for the JVM, so the advice to bump up the memory is sound. c) We need to see the code that you think consumes lots of memory

Comment: thx - I simply upgraded to CF10, and did a fresh install.. The tomcat server seems to handle things better - code runs fine. My production server is still 9 - but I can do all the analysis on my dev box, so...